# Powershell - how to read Azure VM status and a certain tag value?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I need to have a report of VM status and the value of a specific tag.
The VM status part I can handle, but I do not know how add the TAG part into the same script.

```
Get-Azvm -Status | 
    Select-Object Name,ResourceGroupName,PowerState | 
        Where-Object Name -in "SOBA-VM1","SO-VM2","debian01"
```

Please help me.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? i.e. what output are you looking for?

Comment: Well, I need to check: VM Name, VM Status, Resource Group, Tag Name, Tag Value. All in the same view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to switch to using Azure CLI instead of AzPowershell (which I would recommend any day), then here you go:

```
az vm get-instance-view --name MY-VM --resource-group MY-RG --query "{name:name, resourceGroup:resourceGroup, state:instanceView.statuses[1].code, tags:tags}" | ConvertFrom-Json
```

[image]

Also, here the version with PowerShell

```
 Get-Azvm -Status | where-object {$_.Name -in "SOBA-VM1","SO-VM2","debian01"} | select Name,Tags,PowerState,ResourceGroupName
```

Comment: The VMs resides under various Resource Groups. Powershell (Get-Azvm) seems more feasible. Other ideas?

Comment: I just added the pwsh version

Comment: Thank you! And if I also want to filter the tag values or names?

Comment: then just add that to the where-object clause (or add another one after a pipe). this has nothing to do with Azure Pwsh. Just PowerShell syntax

Answer (score 0):

So, in the end, to read a certain Tag value for a VM list, I used the below script:

```
Get-Azvm -Status | 
    Select-Object Name,ResourceGroupName,PowerState,@{Name="running_enddate";Expression={ $_.Tags["running_enddate"] }},@{Name="running_profile";Expression={ $_.Tags["running_profile"] }} | 
        Where-Object {$_.Name -in "VM01","VM02"} | Format-List
```